# rosserial std_msgs

Tags: ros, std-msgs, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably a dumb question, but where do I find the std_msgs folder?  All of the rosserial #includes have something like

`#include <std_msgs/UInt16.h>`

However, the Arduino IDE returns "error: std_msgs/UInt16.h: No such file or directory".  I've searched all around for the files on my computer, but no luck.  I have a sneaking suspicion that this closely related to me being ignorant.  I'm hoping someone can help me see the light.

-Bill

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10814/rosserial-std_msgs/) by [Bill](https://answers.ros.org/users/929/bill/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you actually copied the ros_lib library into your sketchbook as described in the [setup tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup)?

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0